# Syntax error while running "yolk -l"

Tags: python, windows, pip, yolk

I have installed yolk 0.4.3 using pip. But when I tried `yolk -l` to display all installed packages, it showed a syntax error

```
File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\yolk\cli.py" line 262
print "%s %s (%s)" % (project name,dis,version,
                 ^
syntax error :invalid syntax
```

Comment: What Python version are you on?

Answer (score 6):

It seems you're using the package `yolk` (which only works Python 2). To install yolk for Python 3 use the `yolk3k` package:

```
pip install yolk3k
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running a python 2 library with python 3 the versions need to match.

Answer (score 0):

You have Python 2.x syntax with `print` when you are using Python 3.x (notice the `"Python32"` in `"C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\yolk\cli.py"`).  Below is an example written in Python 3.x:

```
>>> print "%s" % "a"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
     print "%s" % "a"
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("%s" % "a")
a
>>>
```

As you can see, you need to use Python 3.x syntax (namely, treat `print` as a built-in, not a keyword).

To fix your problem, make sure your version of yolk works with your version of Python.

Comment: Does yolk work with Python 3? Why does pip happily install it under Python 3?

Comment: @Dan because package maintainer didn't provide information for pip that it's not supported on Py3.x. Pip itself does not guess, it acts accordingly to package metadata.